# Is this common practice for disk quotas on virtual dedicated servers?

Tags: vps, storage

I was a bit surprised when I purchased a VPS with 15GB of storage to find that am left with very little space after Windows' 13GB footprint. I can't even install SQL Server.

Tech support is saying this is normal. I know that if they felt like it they could remove Windows from the quota or adjust it accordingly.

Is this a common practice or should I further pursue the issue with customer service?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is indeed normal. You pay for a fixed amount of virtual disk space and what you use it for is not something the host will care about. You pay for the total space allocated to your VM, not the space free after the OS has been installed. If you installed a small Linux-based Apache+PHP+DB setup, for instance, you might find that 15Gb is really quite roomy for a small project.

Windows 2003 takes a chunk less space by default than Windows 2008, if you have the option of running that in your VM instead, but you would probably still find 15Gb to be cramped especially over time as updates and patches come in. You are right in thinking there isn't much you can do in 15Gb under a modern Windows variant (we use Windows server VMs here for testing, and I always allocate at least 32Gb to each for their system volume, more for 64-bit installs) aside from simple non-data-driven web sites or other low-space services (like a TCP relay or some other simple application).

Answer (score 2):

No, totally normal. Your fault for thinking a 15gb disc is enough to run a full windows and sql server etc. Why did you think they would not count windows? It uses space on their discs, or?

It is totally normal. You basically went too cheap. The server is fine or running a small DNS or web server, but not enough possibly for sql.

Get them to upgrade the discs.

Comment: It seems abnormal that someone would pay $30/month to run a static website. I'm not sure what type of application this is server is intended for. I just want to make sure this is how it is everywhere.

Comment: Is Windows the only OS option the host supports? You can do a lot more out-of-the-box in 15Gb with other operating system options. If Windows *is* the only option then the host is perhaps irresponsible to offer such small VMs.

Comment: No, there are Linux options, but I've got a .NET app. I thought they would not count Windows because I upgraded from a 2003 server with 10GB of storage, and now I can't even get my app up after upgrading unless I use SQL Express.

Comment: Heck, you can get a lot more out of windows if you strip out the GUI. Called Server core. But it is hard to manage as astand alone web server. It is nice if you have a number of servers. Seems like... well... a product without too much use.

Answer (score 0):

Well, This is a problem in witch users and hosting had equal resposabilty (maybe hosting a little more)

First, The users must know about the space they wull need, correct. That was your fault.

But the vendors, must "exclude" SO space from the offer, cos a SQL Guru didnt have to know that 2008 wastes about 15 GB, than 2003 runs on 10 GB and that 2000 needs 5 GB.

*pointed that. The "possible" solution:*

If you have access to the Operating system, there's some folders that u can remove, or "purge" each day.

Normally u can end with about 11 GB of SO, but not many more less.

Hope this help. To delete system folders, be carefull and read the documentation of each folder.